# How can I enable centos-release-SCL on Centos 6.7?

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to install `centos-release-SCL` on CentOS 6.7. I want to do this to get python2.7. I have tried:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=extras install centos-release-SCL
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * extras: anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
No package centos-release-SCL available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have then tried:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=extras list available
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * extras: anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
Available Packages
bakefile.i686                                                                         0.2.8-3.el6.centos                                               extras
centos-release-cr.i686                                                                10:6-0.el6.centos                                                extras
centos-release-virt-common.noarch                                                     1-1.el6.centos                                                   extras
cloud-init.i686                                                                       0.7.5-10.el6.centos.2                                            extras
epel-release.noarch                                                                   6-8                                                              extras
jfsutils.i686                                                                         1.1.13-9.el6                                                     extras
ldns.i686                                                                             1.6.16-7.el6.1                                                   extras
ldns-devel.i686                                                                       1.6.16-7.el6.1                                                   extras
ldns-doc.noarch                                                                       1.6.16-7.el6.1                                                   extras
ldns-python.i686                                                                      1.6.16-7.el6.1                                                   extras
opennx.i686                                                                           0.16-724.el6.centos.1                                            extras
pytest.noarch                                                                         2.3.5-3.el6.centos                                               extras
python-backports.i686                                                                 1.0-3.el6.centos                                                 extras
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname.noarch                                            3.4.0.2-4.el6.centos                                             extras
python-boto.noarch                                                                    2.32.1-1.el6.centos                                              extras
python-chardet.noarch                                                                 2.0.1-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-empy.noarch                                                                    3.3-5.el6.centos                                                 extras
python-jsonpatch.noarch                                                               1.2-2.el6.centos                                                 extras
python-jsonpointer.noarch                                                             1.0-3.el6.centos                                                 extras
python-oauth.noarch                                                                   1.0.1-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-ordereddict.noarch                                                             1.1-2.el6.centos                                                 extras
python-prettytable.noarch                                                             0.7.2-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-py.noarch                                                                      1.4.18-1.el6.centos                                              extras
python-requests.noarch                                                                1.1.0-4.el6.centos                                               extras
python-six.noarch                                                                     1.7.3-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-sphinx10.noarch                                                                1.0.8-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-sphinx10-doc.noarch                                                            1.0.8-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-tornado.noarch                                                                 2.2.1-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-tornado-doc.noarch                                                             2.2.1-1.el6.centos                                               extras
python-urllib3.noarch                                                                 1.5-7.el6.centos                                                 extras
unbound.i686                                                                          1.4.20-23.el6.1                                                  extras
unbound-devel.i686                                                                    1.4.20-23.el6.1                                                  extras
unbound-libs.i686                                                                     1.4.20-23.el6.1                                                  extras
unbound-python.i686                                                                   1.4.20-23.el6.1                                                  extras
wxBase.i686                                                                           2.8.12-1.el6.centos                                              extras
wxGTK.i686                                                                            2.8.12-1.el6.centos                                              extras
wxGTK-devel.i686                                                                      2.8.12-1.el6.centos                                              extras
wxGTK-gl.i686                                                                         2.8.12-1.el6.centos                                              extras
wxGTK-media.i686                                                                      2.8.12-1.el6.centos                                              extras
```

Why is `centos-release-SCL` not available?

Comment: SCL is not available for i686 platform, only for x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it on CentOS 6.7 (also with the intent of installing python2.7, which also worked). So I don't have an answer, other than to show the output (below). However, this isn't a "stock" CentOS 6.7 release; this is the [Hortonworks Sandbox VM](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox). You can try it, too, and see if it works, and see what's different between the two configurations.

```
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
Release:    6.7
Codename:   Final


$ sudo yum install -y centos-release-SCL
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.spro.net
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
 * updates: mirror.pac-12.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package centos-release-scl-rh.noarch 0:2-3.el6.centos will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                              Arch                  Version                         Repository             Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 centos-release-scl-rh                noarch                2-3.el6.centos                  extras                 12 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 12 k
Installed size: 19 k
Downloading Packages:
centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el6.centos.noarch.rpm                                                  |  12 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el6.centos.noarch                                                          1/1 
  Verifying  : centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el6.centos.noarch                                                          1/1 

Installed:
  centos-release-scl-rh.noarch 0:2-3.el6.centos                                                                         

Complete!
```

Comment: your setup is x86_64, topic starter has i686